# Javascript function which submits the form returns boolean

Tags: javascript, submit

We have some code where some function which submits the form returns a boolean. This function is invoked down in `<button>` tag and attached to its onclick event handler like,

`onclick="goBack();"`

What is the use of `return true` here? Without it it works fine too. So people who have worked with legacy code please chime in with your inputs.

```
function goBack() 
{
    document.forms[0].action = "HomePage.jsp";
    document.forms[0].method = "POST";
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nope, no point in the `return`, the name of the function doesn't make sense either if I'm honest.

Comment: A returned value only needs to be passed if the calling function is expecting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return true` statement does nothing in this case.
However, it if were a `return false` combined with `onclick=return goBack()`, it would cancel the `onclick` event, which is why you'll see event handlers return booleans in general.

Also note that `goBack()` might be used in other places that may expect it to return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has mentioned typically returning nothing and returning true both equal success in event handlers, whereas returning false tends to stop the action in it's tracks - prevents bubbling, default handlers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In  this case `onclick="goback()"` does nothing effect on submit function default behaviour and will work normal as excute `goBack()` and submit the form but in case if it is written as:

`onclick="return goBack()"`

Then it means that execute the `goBack()` function and proceed to default behaviour of submit button because it returning `true`.

If it return `false` then it skip the default behaviour of submit function. It is basically used when we want to prevent execution of default behaviour of a `button` or `link`.